# Closed-form expression for sum of Modulo Arithmetic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, modular-arithmetic, closed-form

Is there any closed-form expression or atleast an efficient way to calculate this sum?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N} (a \cdot i) \bmod{M} $$

we can assume $N$, $a$, and $M$ are large enough such that simple looping is not feasible and that period of the progression is also large.

I am aware of the way to calculate sum of first $N$ modulo natural numbers, but I am not able to extend that idea to this series.

Comment: What does $ai\%M$ mean? Does it mean the smallest non-negative residue of $ai$, modulo $M$? Is $N$ a lot larger than $M$? or a lot smaller?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, it meant remainder on division by M, modulo M, edited the expression, we can say N and M are both as large as 10^9, there is no relation between them other than that, both can be upto 10^9.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there were a good way to get an exact answer for $M,N$ that large. This isn't a Project Euler question, is it? Where does it come up?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It appears when finding number of non-negative $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $ax + by <= c$, I am aware there are geometric solutions to find answer to this, but those work with integer vertices, so in this method if we seperate y, then the number of solutions is sum of a series $floor((c - a * x) / b)$ which when simplified yields this series. Also, I found there's a programmatic method which can calculate floored sum of arithmetic progression in logarithmic time, so there must be a way to find this too. https://github.com/atcoder/ac-library/blob/master/atcoder/internal_math.hpp#L182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer to this question the best i can, first of all we suppose $N,M$ large enough and also that $N > M$ and we also know that $(a\cdot i)\mod{M} = (a) mod M \cdot (i) mod M$ hence : $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} (a\cdot i)\mod{M} = (a)\mod{M}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} (i)\mod{M}$. With that, since $N > M$ because if not then the sum is just the sum from $1$ to $N$ times $(a)\mod{M}$. With that, define $C = \big{\lfloor}\frac{N}{M} \big{\rfloor}$ and $r = N - C\cdot M$. And your sum is equal to :

$$a \mod{M}\cdot\bigg{(} \sum_{i = 1}^{r} i + C\cdot M \bigg{)}$$